# What tool or tutorial to use to inject a word into an existing icon?

Tags: icon, automation, overlay

I want to create icons easily. Is there any tool (or tutorial) that can help creating beautiful semantic words that can be added to an existing icon?

Example:

Suppose that we have **[this icon](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/58774/128/apple_folder_icon)**:
[image: Example icon image]

and we want to easily add a word in a beautiful way like **[this](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/58805/128/folder_php_icon)**:
[image: Example icon with text image]

Comment: If you don't want to use html + css, like mast0r suggests, you'd probably want to use something like Gimp or Photoshop ( Since you most likely would be working with the .png version of the icon ).

Comment: You draw it in image editing software.

Comment: What do you mean by semantic in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this: CSS + HTML

- The icon as background image
- The text as normal HTML-text

Comment: That can be done of course, but I want the text to be inserted in the icon in a more beautiful way, like the example I gave , where the text is injected in a flag form.

Comment: @skiabox: the text isn't "injected in a flag form", someone has designed a flag overlay for that icon (or possibly for a family of similar icons), and text has been added to that. So you could add the flag as a PNG overlay between the original icon and HTML text.

Comment: CSS3 offers many opportunities for the text representation: shadows, "embedded" look, stroke, rotation etc. So it is no need to generate a new image every time you need another label for the same icon.